# Path finding on a large list of nodes? Around 100,000 nodes

Tags: c++, spatial, path-finding, quadtree

I have a list of nodes as 2D coordinate (array of float) and the goal is to find how many nodes are **linked** to the source node(given).

Two nodes are defined as linked, if the distance between the nodes is less than or equal to 10. Also, if distance between A and B is <= 10, distance between B and C is <= 10 and distance between A and C > 10, even then, A and C are linked as then path would be is A->B->C. So, it is a typical graph search problem in theory.

**Here is the problem.** I have around 100,000 nodes in a list. Each node is a 2D coordinate point. Since, the list is enormous, conventional traversal and path finding algorithms like DFS or BFS would take up a O(n^2) to construct the adjacency list, which is not ideal and not what I am looking for.

I researched on the internet and found out that Quad Tree or kd Tree probably might be the best to implement in this case. I have made my own Quad Tree class also, I just don't understand how to implement a search algorithm like DFS on it. Or if there is something else that I am missing out on?

Comment: The first step would be to use the quadtree to calculate the adjacencies and use that to make a graph. The second step would be to use DFS (or whatever) on the graph.

Comment: How do I use the quad tree to calculate the adjacencies? Could you please elaborate

Comment: same way you would without the quadtree, but you only have to look at the nodes in nearby quadtree cells.

Comment: Without the quad tree, I would do two for loops from starting index to the size of list of nodes and make an adjacency list for each node given as input. So while using a quad tree instead, what is the limit that I loop over?

Comment: Who said anything about looping over a limit? For each point, you use the quadtree to find points that *might* be close enough, and then you loop over those and check which ones *are* close enough.

Comment: Although if you only have to do it once: if you only have 100,000 nodes you can probably check all the 10,000,000,000 pairs in a matter of seconds or minutes, *and* you don't have to learn how quadtrees work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quadtree groups points by splitting 2D space into quarters, either until each point has a quadrant to itself, or until you reach a minimum size, after which you lump all points within the quadrant into a list.

Since you're trying to find all points within a maximum distance of each point in your source list, you don't need to go all the way down to one-point-per-cell. To pick a cutoff, I would do performance tests on some different values, but as a starting point for minimum quadrant size the maximum connection distance for points is probably a good guess.

So now you have all of your points grouped into a tree and you need to know how to actually find nearby ones.

Since the quadtree encodes spatial information, to find points within a certain distance of any given point, you would descend the quadtree and use that spatial information to exclude entire quadrants from your search. To do this, you would check whether the *nearest* bound of each quadrant is beyond the maximum distance from the point you are searching from. If the closest edge of that quadrant is beyond the maximum distance, then none of the points in that quadrant can possibly be within the maximum distance, so there is no need to explore that part of the tree. (This is similar to how a binary search doesn't need to search parts of a sorted array or tree, because it knows that those parts cannot possibly contain the value being searched for).

Once you get down to the level of the quadtree where you have a single point or list of points, you would do a regular euclidean distance check with those points to see if they were actually within the maximum distance. (Don't forget to check for equality, otherwise you'll find the same point you're searching around).

[image: A quadtree example from wikipedia]

So, for example, if you were searching for points near one of the points in the bottom-right corner of this image, there would be no need to search the other three top-level quadrants because all three of them would be beyond the maximum distance. This would save you from exploring all of the sub-quadrants in those parts of the tree and avoid doing distance comparisons against all of those points.

If, however, you are searching for a point near the edge of a quadrant, you do need to check neighboring quadrants, because the nearest bound will be close enough that you cannot exclude the possibility of a valid point being in that quadrant.

In your particular case, you would make use of this by building the quadtree once, and then looping over the original list of points and doing the search I described above to find all points near that point. You would then use the found-points to build a connectivity graph, which could be efficiently traversed by Depth/Breadth-First-Search or could be given edge-weights to be used with a more complex, weighted search like Dijkstra's Algorithm or A*.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!